# Google Traffic according to data and time

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-api, traffic

I would like to add google map for typical traffic that enables the user to change the date and time to check the traffic history of a certain region. I can do this through the following link
https://www.google.com/maps/@46.8467177,2.2852974,9.83z/data=!5m1!1e1

How can I add this through their javascript API?

Answer (score -1):

I think you're looking for this:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-traffic

Basically what you need to do is instance the TrafficLayer API of google maps, like this:

```
function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 13,
          center: {lat: 34.04924594193164, lng: -118.24104309082031}
        });

        var trafficLayer = new google.maps.TrafficLayer();
        trafficLayer.setMap(map);
}
```

Make sure of have a correct subscription and include your script with the correct path.

Comment: I already added this to my test page but I need the controls to specify which date/time to search for traffic or parameters that i can pass to view the traffic for yesterday for example